# How to increment property in MongoDB collection using $inc

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern

I have a list of articles that have a property `views` and I want to increment that property in the database each time a user clicks on an article title. Currently nothing happens when I do it. Why isn't it working and how can I increment that property each time on click? Here is my React part:

```
  const incrementViews = (id) => {
        var item = posts.find(x => x._id === id);
        item.views += 1;
    }

      <div className="post-title">
          <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`}>
    <h2><a href="#" onClick={() => incrementViews(post._id)}>{post.title}</a>
       </h2>
        </Link>
 </div>
```

and my server.js:

```
// Requiring the dependencies
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;
console.log(BASE_URL)
const itemRoutes = express.Router();
let Comment = require('./comment.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect(BASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true })

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function () {
  console.log('Connection to MongoDB established succesfully!');
});

let collection = connection.collection("posts_with_tags_test");
collection.createIndex(
  {
    postContent: 'text',
    title: 'text'
  }
);


// Serve static assets
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('build'));
}

itemRoutes.route('/').get(async (req, res) => {
  let collection = connection.collection("posts_with_tags_test");
  let response = await collection.find({})
    .toArray();
  res.send(response);
});


itemRoutes.route('/search').post(async (req, res) => {
  let result = await connection.collection("posts_with_tags_test").find({
    $text: {
      $search: req.body.searchString
    }
  }).toArray();
  res.send(result);
});


itemRoutes.route("increment/:id"").post(async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  collection.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $inc: { views: 1 } });
  return res.status(200).json({ msg: "OK" });
});

itemRoutes.route('/comments').get(async (req, res) => {
  let collection = connection.collection("comments");
  let response = await collection.find({})
    .toArray();
  res.send(response);
});


itemRoutes.route('/comments')
  .post((req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let comment = new Comment(req.body);
    comment.save()
      .then(comment => {
        res.status(200).json({ comment })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send('failed')
      })
  });


app.use('/', itemRoutes);
app.use('/comments', itemRoutes);
app.use('/search', itemRoutes);
app.use('/increment', itemRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Server is running on' + ' ' + PORT);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `incrementViews` only increments views on the frontend and never sends any data to the API. One way you can make it work is as follows:

1. `server.js`

```js
itemRoutes.route("/increment/:id").post(async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  collection.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $inc: { views: 1 } });
  return res.status(200).json({ msg: "OK" });
});
```

2. React

```
const incrementViews = (id) => {
  // Assuming your API server is running on port 5000.
  fetch(`http://localhost:5000/increment/${id}`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
};
```

**Update**

The reason you're getting 404 is a missing colon `:` in the route parameters.

```js
// Notice the :id, colon is important.
itemRoutes.route("/increment/:id").post(async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  // ...
});
```

[Here is a demo reproduced on Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/adaptive-sassy-legal?path=server.js). Removed database logic and just added a response messages.
I tested the demo using Postman and it works fine.

On a POST request to `https://adaptive-sassy-legal.glitch.me/increment/123`, should return a response as shown below.

```json
{
  msg: "itemsRoute increment.",
  id: "123"
}
```

**Update 2**

Another thing which I forgot to mention in the previous update was to update the middleware.

```js
// Use only `/increment` instead of `increment/:id`.
app.use("/increment", itemRoutes);
```

[Here is an updated demo](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/endurable-handsomely-tangerine?path=server.js).

Comment: I get this error:  POST https://astroecstatic-backend.herokuapp.com/5ea16d7de7179a52a762d633 404 (Not Found)

Comment: As per your `server.js`, correct route should be https://astroecstatic-backend.herokuapp.com/increment/5ea16d7de7179a52a762d633 but that doesn't work either. If you can update question with a more glance of your server code, I could help.

Comment: Hello, I updated my question with the entire server code

Comment: Hi @JayRobertson, I've updated the answer and added a demo. Give it a try.

Comment: Hi, @kasipavankumar  I added the missing colons, but I still get the same error: POST astroecstatic-backend.herokuapp.com/5ea16d7de7179a52a762d633 404 (Not Found).

Comment: I'm really sorry @JayRobertson, I totally forgot to mention about the middleware. I've updated the answer. Give it a try now.

Comment: I noticed that and changed it to /increment  when I tested, same error.

Comment: In the updated question, there is an error. `increment:id` which is incorrect. Try changing it to `increment/:id` and try again.

Comment: Updated it with ```increment/:id``` still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems in frontend and backend respectively.

- Front-end

  You should use `post` variable as a state variable so as to re-render then component when changes are made on `post`.
- Back-end

  There is no issue with increasing `view` in your code.

  Here, you need to return success status.

Comment: return it like this or? :

itemRoutes.route('/increment').post(async (req, res) => {
 var increment = collection.updateOne(
    { _id: id },
    { $inc: { views: 1 } }
  );
   return res.status(increment);

});

Comment: You should return 200 status not `increment`. So `return res.status(200).send('Success')`